# Selenium handshake failed

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, handshake

I can successfully run my selenium code in my ipynb.  When i move it over to a python file (.py) and run it the following errors occur:

```
[32972:10932:1220/170534.127:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned 
-1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
[32868:10068:1220/170534.129:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(705)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for 
sync.e-planning.net failed: ----- Certificate i=1 (CN=XXXXX,ST=VA,C=US) ----- ERROR: No 
matching issuer found
```

The virtual env is the same.  The python version is the same.  The chromedriver.exe is the same.  I even tried added these:

```
options.add_argument('--disable-proxy-certificate-handler')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
```

Still no luck.  Any advice?  This is really confusing since it works in my ipynb file, but not in my .py file.

Comment: you might try with just "--ignore-certificate-errors".  Not sure if the -spki-list applies anymore, but it has a white-list and only applies when user-data-dir is set according to this: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#ignore-certificate-errors